# signin/signout is not working in authentication in by providers Nextjs 14, next-auth@beta

Tags: authentication, next.js, oauth-2.0, oauth, next-auth

I'm currently facing some challenges with implementing user authentication in my Next.js 14 application using the next-auth package. Despite setting up the necessary routes and configuration files, the default signin and signout routes are not functioning as expected, and the session seems to persist even when the user hasn't signed in. Here are the specifics of my setup:

Environment:

"next": "14.1.0"
"next-auth": "5.0.0-beta.9"
Setup:

I have created the following files under the route src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/:

route.js
options.js
Observations:

When I log the session from header.jsx, I receive the following output:

```
  handlers: { GET: [Function: httpHandler], POST: [Function: httpHandler] },
  auth: [Function (anonymous)],
  signIn: [Function: signIn],
  signOut: [Function: signOut],
  unstable_update: [Function: unstable_update]
}
```

Issues:

The session appears to exist by default, even though the user hasn't signed in.
Attempting to signin/signout at "localhost:3000/api/auth/signin" results in an "Error 500" on the browser.
Request for Help:

Could someone please assist me in troubleshooting these issues? Additionally, please let me know if there are any other details or code snippets I can provide to clarify the situation further.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The session exists, as it is the HTTP session established with the current user. The user might still be unauthenticated, but the backend needs the session to correlate incoming requests, i.e. the backend needs to know these requests come from the same user, even if you don't know yet who the user is. As for the 500 errors — look at some logs, either in the browser or on the server side, and check the concrete problem. We won't be able to help you only knowing that there's a 500 error.